# vuejs - using JWT as param in vue-router

Tags: vue.js, jwt, vue-router

I'm trying to build a vuejs app using quasar framework.
When a user enters his email account and clicks the reset password link that include a JWT as param (http://localhost:8080/reset-password/eyJhbGciOiJIUz...), he gets this error:
Cannot GET /reset-password/eyJhbGciOiJIUz....

This is the relevant code in routes.js:

```
{
        path: '/reset-password/:token',
        component: () => import('pages/profile/ResetPassword.vue')
}
```

When I remove the 2 dots in the JWT param, the VUE page is being loaded.
For example, this link doesn't work:
http://localhost:8080/reset-password/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxLCJrZXkiOiJjMjljZDNmNjYwZDNlMWI4NjRhM2JmNjNkODQxZTc2MiIsImlhdCI6MTYxMzIzMTM3MCwiZXhwIjoxNjEzMjMxNDMwfQ.IEchqNWEGAzVZEQhQQIVl9bnbGcu3I_kCXhG8nmKv2k

But this one does:
http://localhost:8080/reset-password/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxLCJrZXkiOiJjMjljZDNmNjYwZDNlMWI4NjRhM2JmNjNkODQxZTc2MiIsImlhdCI6MTYxMzIzMTM3MCwiZXhwIjoxNjEzMjMxNDMwfQIEchqNWEGAzVZEQhQQIVl9bnbGcu3I_kCXhG8nmKv2k

How can I solve it without changing the JWT token by removing the 2 dots?

Comment: Could you show the link code?

Comment: Hi Dan,
For example: http://localhost:8080/reset-password/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxLCJpYXQiOjE2MTMyMjMxNDUsImV4cCI6MTYxMzIyNDM0NX0.F5ahGRZSiZ0T3ifYmBZSOXcBr0i5dM2oaHRf6VsvPtE

Answer (score 0):

the JWT token is composed of 3 parts (header, payload, verify signature) separated by periods

HEADER: ALGORITHM & TOKEN TYPE

```
in base 64
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9

decode base 64
{
  "alg": "HS256",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

PAYLOAD: DATA

```
in base 64
eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxLCJrZXkiOiJjMjljZDNmNjYwZDNlMWI4NjRhM2JmNjNkODQxZTc2MiIsImlhdCI6MTYxMzIzMJNTM3MCwiZXhzwjMxNjE

decode base 64
{
  "user_id": 1,
  "key": "c29cd3f660d3e1b864a3bf63d841e762",
  "iat": 1613231370,
  "exp": 1613231430
}
```

VERIFY SIGNATURE
IEchqNWEGAzVZEQhQQIVl9bnbGcu3I_kCXhG8nmKv2k

what matters is the payload, this is sent through the url, and use it.

now if you want to recreate the complete jwt, the header will always be the same, the signature can be generated like this

```
HMACSHA256 (
   base64UrlEncode (header) + "." +
   base64UrlEncode (payload),
   your-256-bit-secret
)
```

usually password recovery services only use payload

https://jwt.io

Answer (score 0):

I was fighting with the same problem and solved it by adding the token as a query parameter. That means someone would call my url as

`domain.com/my-path?token=a.b.c`

The example is written for vue3

```js
const myRoute = {
  path: "my-path",
  name: "My Page",
  component: import("./App.vue"),
  beforeEnter( to, from, next ) {
    const { token } = to.query;
    if (typeof token === "string") {
      const jwtRegEx = /(^[A-Za-z0-9-_]*\.[A-Za-z0-9-_]*\.[A-Za-z0-9-_]*$)/;
      const match = token.match(jwtRegEx);
      if (match === null) {
        next(false);
      } else {
        next();
      }
    } else {
      next(false);
    }
  },
};
```

The beforeEach function is there to check that the token is indeed a jwt.